# Compare values in different files and keep non-matching lines

Tags: bash

I have two files with SQL-data in them and I wish to get rid of data in the second file that have a matching course code and student number. The files are looking like this:

File 1:

```
INSERT INTO RegisteredCourses (course,student) VALUES ('BKE974','3941021693');
INSERT INTO RegisteredCourses (course,student) VALUES ('BKE974','5044463260');
INSERT INTO RegisteredCourses (course,student) VALUES ('BKE974','5923001715');
INSERT INTO RegisteredCourses (course,student) VALUES ('DQY359','7539643746');
INSERT INTO RegisteredCourses (course,student) VALUES ('DQY359','9604636424');
INSERT INTO RegisteredCourses (course,student) VALUES ('DQY359','9649249670');
```

File 2:

```
INSERT INTO Queue (course,student,registrationDate) VALUES ('BKE974','3941021693','1354811709');
INSERT INTO Queue (course,student,registrationDate) VALUES ('BKE974','5044463260','1378352712');
INSERT INTO Queue (course,student,registrationDate) VALUES ('BKE974','3421728825','1368144500');
INSERT INTO Queue (course,student,registrationDate) VALUES ('DQY359','7421758823','1375874278');
INSERT INTO Queue (course,student,registrationDate) VALUES ('DQY359','9604636424','1374587707');
INSERT INTO Queue (course,student,registrationDate) VALUES ('DQY359','9649249670','1370542279');
```

I've manipulated the files so that course and student fields are matching in the first two and last two rows of the files. In the first row you can see they have the same course (BKE974) and student (3941021693) values. If these values do not match I would like to print that whole line from File2 to a new file.

I've been trying to use some bash scripting to figure this out and I would love for a bash solution since I'm trying to learn more about bash. I've tried using grep, awk and cut to try to solve this but my knowledge in bash is very lacking :P

EDIT:
So the result I wish to end up with should be these two rows printed to a new file:

```
 INSERT INTO Queue (course,student,registrationDate) VALUES ('BKE974','3421728825','1368144500');
 INSERT INTO Queue (course,student,registrationDate) VALUES ('DQY359','7421758823','1375874278');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using `GNU awk`:

```
awk -F "[()]" 'FNR==NR { a[$(NF-1)]++; next } !(gensub(/(.*),.*/,"\\1","g",$(NF-1)) in a)' File1 File2
```

Results:

```
INSERT INTO Queue (course,student,registrationDate) VALUES ('BKE974','3421728825','1368144500');
INSERT INTO Queue (course,student,registrationDate) VALUES ('DQY359','7421758823','1375874278');
```

Comment: That's so awesome. You are a god :). That will take me a few years to decipher but it works :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
#!/bin/bash
    while read line
    do
            x=`echo "$line" | sed -n "s/.*VALUES (//p" | sed -n "s/);//p"`;
            sed -i   '/'$x'/d' file2.txt
    done<file1.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, this prints a list of what seems to be unique courses and students. I would like to print the complete line though to keep the insert statement complete.

Comment: This not only prints the value. check the file2.txt.. All the entries found are deleted also..

Comment: I have removed the echo $x.. because that is not needed... and what do you want to print?? I didnt get you

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. I have updated the question to also show the result I'm trying to get.